# Serving Flask-RESTPlus on https server

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-restplus

I am relatively new to python and I created a micro service using [flask-resplus](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html). 
Works fine on my computer and on the dev server served with http. 
I dont have control on where the microservice could be deployed. In these case it seems is behind a load balancer(not sure of details), served with https.

The actual errors given by the browser: Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.

When i check the network developer tools i see it fails loading swagger.json. But is checking it using:
http://hostname/api/swagger.json, instead of https.

I have been googling, and i ran into discussions of [this](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/54) issue.
And [this](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/pull/128) seemed to be the fix that could work without me having to change the library or configurations on the server.

However still i couldnt get it to work.

This is what i have:

on the api file:

```
api_blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
api = Api(api_blueprint, doc='/doc/', version='1.0', title='My api',
          description="My api")
```

on the main app file:

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix

from lib.api import api_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)

app.wsgi_app = ProxyFix(app.wsgi_app)
app.register_blueprint(api_blueprint)
```

Also tried adding:

```
app.config['SERVER_URL'] = 'http://testfsdf.co.za' # but it dont look like is being considered
```

Using flask-restplus==0.9.2,

Any solution will be appreciated, as long as i dont need to make configurations on the container where the service will be deployed 
(am ok with setting environment variables), i.e. service need to be self contained. And if there is a version of flask-resplus that i can install with pip, that already has a fix i can appreciate.

Thanks a lot guys,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Overide API class with `_scheme='https'` option in `spec` property.

```
class MyApi(Api):
    @property
    def specs_url(self):
        """Monkey patch for HTTPS"""
        scheme = 'http' if '5000' in self.base_url else 'https'
        return url_for(self.endpoint('specs'), _external=True, _scheme=scheme)

api = MyApi(api_blueprint, doc='/doc/', version='1.0', title='My api',
        description="My api")
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me when running my application in production. But when I run my app locally, I get the following response "Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings" from calling localhost:5000.

Is there anyway I can get this to run the same in both prod and locally?

Comment: I got your problem.  Just use default scheme  in local enviroment, see edited code

Answer (score 2):

The solution above works like a charm. There are couple of things you should check.

1. Before applying the fix, make sure in your *chrome developertools -> Network* tab that whenever you reload the page(in https server) that shows the swagger UI, you get a mixed content error for swagger.json request.
2. The solution in the above post solves the issue when deployed on an https server but locally it might give issue. For that you can use the environment variable trick.
3. Set a custom environment variable or any variable which is already there on your https server while deploying your app. Check for the existence of that environment variable before applying the solution to make sure your app in running in the https server.

Now when you run the app locally, this hack won't be applied and swagger.json would be served through *http* and in your server it would be served via *https*. Implementation might look similar to this.

```
import os
from flask import url_for
from flask_restplus import Api

app = Flask( __name__)
if os.environ.get('CUSTOM_ENV_VAR'):
    @property
    def specs_url(self):
        return url_for(self.endpoint('specs'), _external=True, _scheme='https')
    Api.specs_url = specs_url
api = Api(app)
```

Comment: I like to make use of the `FLASK_ENV` variable that is all already in play for the flask env. ref: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/?highlight=flask_env. Set / export FLASK_ENV=development for your http scheme.